# iOS: creating an expandable label

Tags: ios, swift, text, label, expandable

I'm trying to create an expandable label that looks like the one in the picture:
[image]

I have two problems:

1. How do I make the label truncate the tail such that it leaves enough place for the **More** button/clickable text?
2. How do I place the **More** text?

Maybe, I am going about it the wrong way? Instead of playing with the number of lines, should I maybe try to calculate how much text goes into one and a half line and present it only, and then when clicking **More** I present the whole text?

Would appreciate any advice, thanks!

Comment: How are you going to put it back once the text label is expanded?

Comment: I think you can add a button to overlap the end of the last line of the text label. Like Apple is doing on the App Store: 
https://prnt.sc/pdsc4f

Answer (score 3):

You can use this library to achieve your expected output.

https://github.com/apploft/ExpandableLabel

Specify the number of lines you want to display default.

```
expandableLabel.numberOfLines = 2
```

Set true if the label should be collapsed or false for expanded.

```
expandableLabel.collapsed = true
```

collapsedAttributedLink
Set the link name that is shown when collapsed.

```
expandableLabel.collapsedAttributedLink = NSAttributedString(string: "More")
```

expandedAttributedLink
Set the link name that is shown when expanded. It is optional and can be nil.

```
expandableLabel.expandedAttributedLink = NSAttributedString(string: "Less")
```